# How to create a developer provisioning profile request in iOS Enterprise Account?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, enterprise, account

We have iOS Enterprise Account. Right now we want to add a developer to our team, and the developer will create a developer provisioning profile. The problem is the new added developer doesn't see the Provisioning Profile tag in his apple account. Any one has any idea how does the new added developer create a provisioning profile?

Thanks you !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Steps:

- You invite the new developer to join your development team by sending an invitation from the Member Center at http://developer.apple.com/ios (There should be a "People" item on the navigation bar at the top of the page. Apple has a good screenshot in the [Tools Workflow Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH6-SW3))
- Developer accepts invitation.
- Developer creates a certificate signing request using Keychain Access and uploads it to the portal.
- An administrator on your team approves the certificate.
- Administrator creates a new provision profile and adds the developer, or simply adds the developer to an existing profile.
- Developer downloads signed certificate and provision profile from portal.

Comment: Can i also envite a developer, who works on the same mac? For instance: the agent certificate has been created on the mac and i want also a developer certificate for myself on the same mac. Sounds maybe wired, but i probably need it, to do a work around for an XCode issue (4.3 -> duplicated certificate)

Comment: @NicTesla A little late, but yes, you can have multiple certificates on the same machine. If two people are sharing a computer, it's of course best to set up separate user accounts.

Comment: @Caleb Thy! I guess, two user accounts would have solved my problem also. I fixed this issue by creating a new "Key chain" within the keychain app and added the certificate and priv/public key in there and Xcode was able to find the right ones. But the recent update (Xcode 4.3.1) solved it already :)

Comment: @Caleb, Should administrator needs to create App id and UDID in order to create development provisioning profile? As we(member) can't create  app id and UDID. right?

Comment: Then what is the use of having member account except downloadbles?

Comment: @G.Ganesh The use is exactly that: it lets you to submit your certificate and get it signed, and it lets you download a development provisioning profile so that you can run your code on test devices. If you want everyone on your team to be able to add device ID's and create provisioning profiles, just make everyone an administrator. But since slots for test devices are a limited resource (you're limited to 100 in any given year), it can be useful to limit the ability to add new ones to a few team members.

Comment: Hi @Caleb, I have a client who's got a enterprise account and has added me as an Admin. Mind you, I don't have a paid developer account, only a normal unpaid one. In your third step you've said create a certificate signing request and upload it to the portal. I need to know which portal you're referring to?

Answer (score 3):

Only `Agent` user type has rights to create and download **App ID, certificate, and provisioning profiles**.

**Edited:** due to comments from peers:-

The `Admin` user type can only create developer provisioning profile but cannot create distribution (`Adhoc` or `App Store`) provisioning profile.

However `Member` user type can only see or download these things. They can't see any option to create or add new.

So, you need to assign `Admin` role to the new user in order to allow him to create `developer provisioning profile`.

Comment: I'm an admin in my company's profile, and I can in fact create AppID's, certificates and provisioning profiles, but only for development.

Comment: This is wrong. Administrators can create development profiles and add team members to them. It's true that only the team agent can create a distribution profile, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have admin permissions for that. Go to member center -> people and check if he's admin.

Comment: Or you can add his certificate to your working profile, and send the provisioning profile to him...